# Commands.Stage() doesn't increment Staged.Count when staging untracked files with LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

Following block works when I stage at least one tracked file. But when I stage only untracked files, `repo.RetrieveStatus().Staged.Count` equals to zero (I expect it to be incremented by the number of files staged), thus doesn't satisfy if condition and don't commit.

```
using (var repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(RepoPath))
    {
        Commands.Stage("*");
        Signature author = new Signature(username, email, DateTime.Now);
        Signature committer = author;
        if (repo.RetrieveStatus().Staged.Any())
        {
            Commit commit = repo.Commit(CommitMessage, author, committer);
            Console.WriteLine(commit.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Is this a bug, or I am misusing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the `Staged` collection is:

> List of files added to the index, which are already in the current commit with different content

ie, these correspond to the "modified" in the "changes to be committed" area of `git-status`, or the `M` status to `git-status --short`.

These do not, by definition, include newly added files that are staged.  For that, you want to also examine the `Added` collection, which is:

> List of files added to the index, which are not in the current commit

ie, these correspond to the "new files" in the "changes to be committed" area of `git-status`, or the `A` status to `git status --short`.

However, you probably want to also consider *all* staged changes, which I think is what you're trying to do.  You would want to look at these collections on the status:

> `Added`: List of files added to the index, which are not in the current commit
>   `Staged`: List of files added to the index, which are already in the current commit with different content
>   `Removed`: List of files removed from the index but are existent in the current commit
>   `RenamedInIndex`: List of files that were renamed and staged (if you requested renames).

At the moment there is no function that will return a list of all staged changes, which seems like an oversight (and one that would be easy to correct, if you wanted to submit a pull request to LibGit2Sharp!)

Comment: Thank you, perhaps I can send a pull request to fix this.